# What does this JavaScript notation do: Object[key](value)

Tags: javascript

I'm not really sure what's going on here, but in a nutshell I've seen this:

```
Object[key](value);
```

In line 1088 of [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/tarruda/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js#L1088):

```
  $.fn.datetimepicker = function ( option, val ) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this),
      data = $this.data('datetimepicker'),
      options = typeof option === 'object' && option;
      if (!data) {
        $this.data('datetimepicker', (data = new DateTimePicker(
          this, $.extend({}, $.fn.datetimepicker.defaults,options))));
      }
      // Line below:
      if (typeof option === 'string') data[option](val);
    });
  };
```

Would anyone be able to answer what is going on?

I thought maybe it was assigning the value to the key in the object but when I tried doing something similar in the developer console (working in chrome v.33) it doesn't work.

Comment: `obj[key]` is a function, this calls that function passing in `value` as a parameter.

Comment: functions are objects in javascript and can be stored like a regular objects.

Comment: Thanks guys that's really cleared it up. I'll mark the question as solved as soon as the time limit is up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object` is a Javascript object that you can declare like this:

```
var obj = {};
```

Then a property is created (whose name is contained in the `key` variable) with a function as its value:

```
var obj['myfunction'] = function() { alert('Hello!'); };
```

So now,you have a function stored in your object 'obj' in the 'myfunction' key.

Since it's a function you execute it using '()', which results in:

```
obj['myfunction']()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var property = 'method';
// multiple ways to access properties
object.method === object['method'] === object[property];
// and you can use any syntax to call the method
// These all call `object.method`:
object.method() === object['method']() === object[property]();
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators

Answer (score 1):

To access properties of an object in JavaScript you can either use the dot notation. i.e: `Object.property` or the string notation (also called bracket notation) `Object[property]`.

Both are valid, though the dot notation doesn't work with property names containing spaces for example, such as `Object.property name` is invalid, while `Object['property name']` is valid.

Given your example, `Object[key](value)` you are accessing a property of which the name is stored in the `key` from the `Object` object. The property happens to be a method and you can execute it passing `value` as the parameter.

Imagine the object to look like this:

```
Object = {
    myProp: function(newValue){
        // do something with newValue
    }
}
```

It would be perfectly fine to call it using the string notation if the method name is stored in a variable:

```
var key = 'myProp';
Object[key](value);
```

or if you don't need a variable you can also call it directly using the dot notation:

```
Object.myProp(value);
```

---

Resources: [**MDN on Property Accessors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

---

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just a hack to do something like:

```
var method = "create";
var prop = new String();
var str = Object[method](prop);
```

So you invoke a method `create` with parameter `prop`.